# Regarding the security of javascript for submitting proper data to servers

Tags: javascript, html, security

I was wondering if it was possible for users to edit the javascript on a page.

For example, if a submit button event handler in javascript has a condition like this:

```
if (!txtName.match(/^[\w ]+$/)) {
    alert("Please use only letters, numbers, underscores and spaces in your name.");
    return;
}
```

Do I also have to validate the name on the server or can I trust that an improper name cannot be sent to the server? Basically, can the javascript be manipulated by the user to bypass this sort of check?

If not, could packet injection be used to submit an invalid name? I don't know much about security so I was just curious about these sorts of issues.... Okay thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript form validation on client side without server side - is it safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113422/javascript-form-validation-on-client-side-without-server-side-is-it-safe) **one of many duplicated questions**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I also have to validate the name on the server

Yes

> or can I trust that an improper name cannot be sent to the server?

No

> Basically, can the javascript be manipulated by the user to bypass this sort of check?

Manipulated.

Turned off.

When it comes to validation, it can only be used to save the user time (but avoiding server round trips), not security.

> Could packet injection be used to submit an invalid name?

Yes.

Manually constructing an HTTP request would be much easier though.

Answer (score 1):

You must perform server-side validation too. As you've pointed out, there are numerous ways to inject information. For one, they can just turn Javascript off. Or, they can intercept and modify the network request.

Client-side should only be used to supplement, and not replace, server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

Always validate on the server side. You should never trust data posted to your server and can lead to serious security risks.